# Google Analytics Notification API

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-api

I would like to create an automate who collects Notifications, those are into the clock icon at the top right, to make a summary at the end of the day through an email.

I was searching but I don't found anything: is existing an API who retrieved the notifications from Google Analytics ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. The only APIs available are listed below, none of them provide notifications information.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt

An alternative is to create [custom alerts](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033021?hl=en) with emails, then use tools like Zapier to process those emails in an automated fashion.

Comment: Thanks Max for your response :)